# std::hash value on char* value and not on memory address?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

As stated in this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash):

> There is no specialization for C strings. std::hash produces a hash of the value of the pointer (the memory address), it does not examine the contents of any character array.

Which means that with the same `char*` value, different hashcodes could be produced. For example, having this code:

```
//MOK and MOV are template arguments
void emit(MOK key, MOV value) {
    auto h = hash<MOK>()(key);
    cout<<"key="<<key<<" h="<<h<<endl;
    ...
```

This is the output produced by calling 4 times `emit()` on the same `key` (with `MOK=char*`) value (but 4 different tokens/string objects):

```
key=hello h=140311481289184
key=hello h=140311414180320
key=hello h=140311414180326
key=hello h=140311481289190
```

How can I obtain the same hash code for `char*`? I'd prefer not to use `boost`

Comment: So is your goal to make `"hello, world"` and `std::string {"hello, world"}` hash to the same value?

Comment: There _is_ a specialization for `std::string`, but not for C strings. Can you show the actual code that gets this result with `std::string`?

Comment: Why would you want to hash a string based on the address of the pointer?

Comment: Sorry, fixed with `char*` instead of `string`

Comment: @NathanOliver I think the OP wants to go the opposite direction: hashing C-style strings based on the data pointed to. Otherwise, it would just be a matter of hashing `s.c_str()`.

Comment: Can you not work with `std::string`s?

Comment: Why don't you then specialize `std::hash<const char*>`?

Comment: You could create your own specialization for char* that wraps it in a `std::string` and then returns the hash of that?

Comment: @vsoftco That's...horrible. Specializing a standard library template for a built-in type is a one-way ticket to UB land.

Comment: @T.C. Still not clear why....

Comment: @vsoftco Because it violates the blanket prohibition in [\[namespace.std\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#1).

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, learned something today. I didn't know that fundamental types cannot be specialized in `std`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is of course the trivial (and slow) solution of creating a temporary `std::string` and hashing that one.  If you don't want to do this, I'm afraid you will have to implement your own hash function. Sadly enough, the current C++ standard library doesn't provide general purpose hash algorithms disentangled from object-specific hash solutions. (But there is [some hope](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html) this could change in the future.)

Suppose you had a function

```
std::size_t
hash_bytes(const void * data, std::size_t size) noexcept;
```

that would take an address and a size and return you a hash computed from the that many bytes following that address.  With the help of that function, you could easily write

```
template <typename T>
struct myhash
{
  std::size_t
  operator()(const T& obj) const noexcept
  {
    // Fallback implementation.
    auto hashfn = std::hash<T> {};
    return hashfn(obj);
  }
};
```

and then specialize it for the types you're interested in.

```
template <>
struct myhash<std::string>
{
  std::size_t
  operator()(const std::string& s) const noexcept
  {
    return hash_bytes(s.data(), s.size());
  }
};

template <>
struct myhash<const char *>
{
  std::size_t
  operator()(const char *const s) const noexcept
  {
    return hash_bytes(s, std::strlen(s));
  }
};
```

This leaves you only with the exercise of implementing `hash_bytes`. Fortunately, there are some fairly good hash functions that are rather easy to implement. My go-to algorithm for simple hashing is the [Fowler-Noll-Vo hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function). You can implement it in five lines of code; see the linked Wikipedia article.

If you want to get a bit fancy, consider the following implementation. First, I define a generic `template` that can be specialized for any version of the FNV-1a hash function.

```
template <typename ResultT, ResultT OffsetBasis, ResultT Prime>
class basic_fnv1a final
{

  static_assert(std::is_unsigned<ResultT>::value, "need unsigned integer");

public:

  using result_type = ResultT;

private:

  result_type state_ {};

public:

  constexpr
  basic_fnv1a() noexcept : state_ {OffsetBasis}
  {
  }

  constexpr void
  update(const void *const data, const std::size_t size) noexcept
  {
    const auto cdata = static_cast<const unsigned char *>(data);
    auto acc = this->state_;
    for (auto i = std::size_t {}; i < size; ++i)
      {
        const auto next = std::size_t {cdata[i]};
        acc = (acc ^ next) * Prime;
      }
    this->state_ = acc;
  }

  constexpr result_type
  digest() const noexcept
  {
    return this->state_;
  }

};
```

Next, I provide aliases for the 32 and 64 bit versions.  The parameters were taken from [Landon Curt Noll's website](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/index.html).

```
using fnv1a_32 = basic_fnv1a<std::uint32_t,
                             UINT32_C(2166136261),
                             UINT32_C(16777619)>;

using fnv1a_64 = basic_fnv1a<std::uint64_t,
                             UINT64_C(14695981039346656037),
                             UINT64_C(1099511628211)>;
```

Finally, I provide type meta-functions to select a version of the algorithm given the wanted number of bits.

```
template <std::size_t Bits>
struct fnv1a;

template <>
struct fnv1a<32>
{
  using type = fnv1a_32;
};

template <>
struct fnv1a<64>
{
  using type = fnv1a_64;
};

template <std::size_t Bits>
using fnv1a_t = typename fnv1a<Bits>::type;
```

And with that, we're good to go.

```
constexpr std::size_t
hash_bytes(const void *const data, const std::size_t size) noexcept
{
  auto hashfn = fnv1a_t<CHAR_BIT * sizeof(std::size_t)> {};
  hashfn.update(data, size);
  return hashfn.digest();
}
```

Note how this code automatically adapts to platforms where `std::size_t` is 32 or 64 bits wide.

Comment: Why not specialize std::hash directly? It shouldn't be an exception IIRC.

Comment: Also in the future, we'll probably be able to do `std::hash(std::string_view("some_key"))` which should be cheap.

Comment: @BillLynch I was thinking of that too, it would be pretty cool. But I also remember people debating whether equivalence on `std::string_view` should be defined in terms of pointer addresses or pointed-to memory. If it were the former, we couldn't use it for hashing. Do you happen to know what the current status is?

Comment: @5gon12eder: cppreference says that if `string_view("abc") == string_view("abc")` then `hash(string_view("abc")) == hash(string_view("abc"))`. So unless they decide to make an unhelpful equality operator, we should be fine.

Comment: This is a hell of answer. Thank you.

Comment: BTW @5gon12eder I don't understand why the compiler returns me the error `error: assignment of member ‘basic_fnv1a<long unsigned int, 14695981039346656037ul, 1099511628211ul>::state_’ in read-only object
     this->state_ = acc;`

Comment: @justHelloWorld I don't understand it either. Did you use the code from the answer? It compiles fine for me. Note that this is C++14, though and you'd need a pretty recent compiler. If you're using an older compiler, try removing the `constexpr`s, they are not valid in C++11.

Comment: @5gon12eder you were right: the error was given because I'm using C++11. So, do you confirm me that with your code the only thing to do in case we want to introduce a new type is to specialize `myHash` with the new type **without touching anything else** (like `hash_bytes` or `basic_fnv1a` definitions)?

Comment: @justHelloWorld Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @5gon12eder It might sound silly. If I specialize std::hash for char * in std namespace, will that specialization be available across the shared library or exe?

Answer (score 14):

In C++17 you should use `std::hash<std::string_view>` which works seamlessly since `const char*` can be implicitly converted to it.

Answer (score 9):

I've had to do this before and ended up writing a function to do this, with essentially the same implementation as [Java's String hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()#The_java.lang.String_hash_function):

```
size_t hash_c_string(const char* p, size_t s) {
    size_t result = 0;
    const size_t prime = 31;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
        result = p[i] + (result * prime);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Mind you, this is NOT a cryptographically secure hash, but it is fast enough and yields good results.

Answer (score 6):

Since C++17 added [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string_view) including a `std::hash` specialization for it you can use that to compute the hash value of a C-string.

Example:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <cstring>

static size_t hash_cstr(const char *s)
{
    return std::hash<std::string_view>()(std::string_view(s, std::strlen(s)));
}
```

---

If you have to deal with a pre-C++17 compiler you can check your STL for an implementation defined hash function and call that.

For example, libstdc++ (which is what GCC uses by default) provides `std::_Hash_bytes` which can be called like this:

```
#include <functional>
// -> which finally includes /usr/include/c++/$x/bits/hash_bytes.h
#include <cstring>

static size_t hash_cstr_gnu(const char *s)
{
    const size_t seed = 0;
    return std::_Hash_bytes(s, std::strlen(s), seed);
}
```

Comment: const char * s = "foo"
h1 =  std::hash<std::string_view>{}(std::string_view(s, std::strlen(s)))

std::string s2 ("foo")
h2 =  std::hash<std::string>{}(s2)

Will s1 == s2 ?

Comment: @sandwood I don't see where you define s1. Did you mean to ask whether `h1 == h2`, instead? The C++ standard doesn't require that `h1` and `h2` from your example will be equal. However, you can [easily create a string view of your std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view), as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::collate::hash
e.g. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/collate/hash/