# std::unordered_map find() operation not working in GCC7

Tags: c++

I am working on porting my c++ application from GCC4.7 to GCC7 and ran into an issue where `std::hash_map` `find()` function returns `null` result for keys which are present in map.

**Existing code:**

```
struct eqfunc {
  bool operator()(const char* const &s1, const char* const &s2) const {
    std::cout << "eqfunc in action " << s1 << " - " << s2 << std::endl;
    return strcmp(s1,s2) == 0;
  }
};

template <typename T> class customMap : public std::hash_map<const char*,T,std::hash<const char*>,eqfunc> {};

customMap<const char*> cstmMap;
std::cout << "Insert abc" << std::endl;
cstmMap["abc"] = "ABC";
std::cout << "Insert def" << std::endl;
cstmMap["def"] = "DEF";
std::cout << "Insert xyz" << std::endl;
cstmMap["xyz"] = "XYZ";

std::cout << "Find def in cstmMap" << std::endl;
string findString("def");
customMap<const char*>::iterator ptr = cstmMap.find((char *)findString.c_str());
LOG_INFO("output ptr %s", ptr);
```

This was working fine in GCC4.7 platform. When I ported the code to GCC7, I noticed the behaviour where find() returns `null` result even for keys which are present in the map.

**Sample run output in GCC7**

```
Insert abc
Insert def
Insert xyz
Find def in cstmMap
output ptr (null)
```

Updated `std::hash_map` to `std::unordered_map` doesn't work either:

```
template <typename T> class customMap : public std::unordered_map<const char*,T,std::hash<const char*>,eqfunc> {};
```

Another weird behaviour I noticed using `std::unordered_map` is that `eqfunc` is not executed in  consistent pattern across multiple runs

**Sample 1 run**

```
Insert abc
Insert def
eqfunc in action def - abc
Insert xyz
Find def in cstmMap
eqfunc in action def - xyz
output ptr (null)
```

**Sample 2 run**

```
Insert abc
Insert def
eqfunc in action def - abc
Insert xyz
Find def in cstmMap
output ptr (null)
```

**NOTE:** This is very large code base and changing `const char *` to `std::string` is not straightforward and requires a lot of work.

I am wondering if there are any work arounds to get it working with existing `const char *` data type for the map's key. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: `find()` never returns `null`. Please include the actual output

Comment: You need a custom hash function as well.  By default `std::unordered_map` will be hashing the pointers (not what they point to).  So if two literal c-string are identical but held at different addresses in memory they will not hash the same.  Changes in constant-folding may produce the differences you are seeing.

Comment: `std::hash<const char*>` looks very sus. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash): "There is no specialization for C strings. std::hash<const char*> produces a hash of the value of the pointer (the memory address), it does not examine the contents of any character array. "

Comment: The posted code is as broken in gcc 4.7 as it is in gcc 7.

Comment: Frank, may I know why you are saying that this code is broken in ggc 4.7.

Comment: @karthik.zorfy code relies in two identical constant c-strings being held at the same memory address - there is no guarantee of this.

Comment: Because these requirements come from the language specification, not the implementation. It was just an accident that it seemed to work in the older version.

Comment: Folks, the code includes custom equals function to compare the actual content of the `const char *` content and not the address.

Comment: @karthik.zorfy Equals is only used if the hashes are the same.  Hash to find the bucket then equals to check each item in the bucket.  If hash is not working/broken then equals is irrelevant.

Comment: _"...There is no specialization for C strings. std::hash<const char*> produces a hash of the value of the pointer (the memory address), it does not examine the contents of any character array...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've discovered that `std::hash<const char*>` hashes the actual pointer - not the C string it points at. Sometimes `"def"` and the second `"def"` will actually have the same pointer value. It depends on how the compiler optimized it.

To use C strings, you need to provide a hash functor for C strings. Here's one example:

```
#include <string_view>

struct cstring_hash {
    size_t operator()(std::string_view str) const {
        return std::hash<std::string_view>{}(str);
    }
};
```

And redefine the container:

```
template <typename T>
class customMap : public std::unordered_map<const char*, T, cstring_hash, eqfunc> {
    // To be able to use ctors:
    using std::unordered_map<const char*, T, cstring_hash, eqfunc>::unordered_map;
};
```

The added `using` of the `unordered_map`s constructors makes it possible to construct the map in a simpler way:

```
int main() {
    customMap<const char*> cstmMap{
        {"abc", "ABC"},
        {"def", "DEF"},
        {"xyz", "XYZ"},
    };

    std::string findString("def");
    auto ptr = cstmMap.find(findString.c_str());
    std::cout << ptr->second << '\n';            // prints DEF
}
```

If you are using a C++ version prior to C++17, you could replace `cstring_hash` by picking a good enough hash function. Here's one that probably does the job:

```
namespace detail {
    static const auto S = // shift constant
        sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(uint64_t) ? 16u : 32u;
    static const auto C = // multiplication constant
        sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(uint64_t) ? 23456789u : 0xBB67AE8584CAA73Bull;
}

#if __cpp_constexpr >= 201304L
  #define RELAXEDCONSTEXPR constexpr
#else
  #define RELAXEDCONSTEXPR
#endif

struct cstring_hash {
    RELAXEDCONSTEXPR size_t operator()(const char *s) const {
        size_t h = 0;
        
        for(; *s; ++s) {
            h = h * detail::C + static_cast<unsigned char>(*s);
            h ^= h >> detail::S;
        }
        
        return h *= detail::C;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ted, Thanks for the answer. As I mentioned in the question this is a very large code base and changing the data type from `const char *` to a different one would require a lot of work and I am looking for a workaround to make it work with the `const char *` key type. As folks suggested, it seems I can get it working with `const char *` by defining a custom hash function.

Comment: @karthik.zorfy Ok, I changed my answer to that instead.

Comment: Apparently `std::string_view` is only available in c++17 or newer and I couldn't use it in my project. Nevertheless, I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @karthik.zorfy Yes, ok, I added a section on that. If you want me to I can add an actual hash function to replace the `std::string` hash in the answer later.

Comment: I came up with the below custom hash function. Can you once review and add your comments. If this looks good, please add it to your answer. Might come in handy for someone else.


```
struct customHash {
  inline size_t operator()(const char* str) const {
    size_t result = 0;
    for (; *str != '\0'; str++) {
      result = 5 * result + static_cast<size_t>(*str);
    }
    return result;
  }
};

```

Comment: Came across this post which looks handy for defining custom has function - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597260/stdhash-value-on-char-value-and-not-on-memory-address

Comment: @karthik.zorfy I can't judge if it's good by just looking at it (I'm not that good with hashes). I usually pick a well tested hash function off the shelf - or ask a friend who gives me one. :-) Are you using C++11 or later?